# Image Fixed Degree in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a js file, in it there is image, which I like to change its angle to 90 degree fixed position. please tell me how to modify the code. .

```
facilitiesText = paper.image("images/wheel/test2.png", 130, 0, 70, 40).attr(attrText)
```

I have to make this image to 90 degree fixed position

This is how it looks like
 [image: This is what it looks like]

This is what I want it to be
[image: This is what I want]

[JS FILE](http://jsfiddle.net/zain0788/3C47K/)

Comment: try .transform('r90'); on end end maybe

Comment: @lan: I tried it but its getting animated back to previous position

Comment: Do you want to see the whole coding

Comment: If you can put an example on a jsfiddle, it would be helpful.

Comment: @lan: I dono how am i gonna give you an example.. .please see fiddle .js file http://jsfiddle.net/zain0788/3C47K/

Comment: Hard to look through all of that to debug (maybe thats part of the problem, you should be able to isolate it easy). I would imagine your animation is overriding your previous transform setting. So you would need to add the original rotation to the starting transform, so there are two transforms, like 'myAnimationTransform' + 'r90' or something.